# GetIt not being able to correctly find registered type based on abstract class/interface, but succeeds with concrete class

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection

**Context**

I am using:

- `Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale en-US)`
- `get_it: ^7.2.0`.

I have the following injector which includes the `CategoryRepositoryAdapter` service (that implements `CategoryRepositoryPort`):

```dart
// injector.dart
final injector = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> initializeDependencies() async {

  // Rest Client
  injector.registerSingleton<Dio>(Dio());

  // Database Client
  final database = await $FloorMoneyDatabase
      .databaseBuilder(kDatabaseName)
      .build();
  injector.registerSingleton<MoneyDatabase>(database);

  // Database Mappers and Repositories
  injector.registerSingleton<CategoryEntityMapper>(
      CategoryEntityMapper()
  );

  injector.registerSingleton<CategoryRepositoryPort>(    // <--- problem is here
      CategoryRepositoryAdapter(injector(), injector())
  );

  // UI Handlers
  injector.registerSingleton<CategoryHandlerPort>(
      CategoryHandler(injector())
  );

  // Blocs
  injector.registerFactory<LocalCategoryBloc>(
        () => LocalCategoryBloc(injector())
  );

}
```

The class that calls that service looks like this:

```dart
// category.handler.dart
class CategoryHandler implements CategoryHandlerPort {
  final CategoryRepositoryPort _repository;  // <--- problem is here

  const CategoryHandler(this._repository);

  Stream<Category?> findAllCategories() {
    ...
  }

  Future<Category?> findCategoryById(int id) {
    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

And the concrete service to inject looks like this:

```dart
// category.repository_adapter.dart
class CategoryRepositoryAdapter implements CategoryRepositoryPort {
  final MoneyDatabase _database;
  final CategoryEntityMapper _map;

  const CategoryRepositoryAdapter(this._database, this._map);

  @override
  Stream<Category> findAllCategories() async* {
    ...
  }

  @override
  Future<Category?> findCategoryById(int id) async {
    ...
  }

  @override
  Future<void> insertCategory(Category category) {
    ...
  }

  @override
  Future<void> removeCategory(Category category) {
    ...
  }

}
```

**Error**

When I run the application with the above, I get the error:

```sh
Object/factory with  type CategoryRepositoryAdapter is not registered inside GetIt. 
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
```

**Workaround**

If I register the concrete class, `CategoryRepositoryAdapter`, instead of the abstract class that it implements, `CategoryRepositoryPort`, and reference the former in the calling class, all works fine:

```dart
// injector.dart
  ...
  injector.registerSingleton<CategoryRepositoryAdapter>(    // <-- changed this to point to concrete class
      CategoryRepositoryAdapter(injector(), injector())
  );
  ...
```

```dart
// category.handler.dart
class CategoryHandler implements CategoryHandlerPort {
  final CategoryRepositoryAdapter _repository;    // <-- changed this to point to concrete class

  const CategoryHandler(this._repository);
  ...
```

**Summary**

- `get_it` is registering the service successfully when using the concrete class;
- `get_it` is NOT registering the service when using the abstract class.

Any clues what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Looking around, I found that I was calling the concrete class `CategoryRepositoryAdapter` elsewhere; and that was making `get_it` confused.

Calling the abstract class `CategoryRepositoryPort` everywhere solved it.